# OpenCV multithread leaks memory

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

I'm attempting to use the MergeMertens exposure stacking in OpenCV (C++) with multiple threads to speed it up. It does speed up but memory keeps going up and up after each call to mergeExposuresInThread().

Right now it is executing 4 threads before starting on the next 4.
It merges 5 different frames from known (o well guessed) filenames based on a base string.

What is wrong here? I feel that I'm releasing all objects that I have allocated and have read most posts about this on stackoverflow.

After about 30-40 times executing mergeExposuresInThread(...) the application gets killed by the operating system (Ubuntu 16.04) (sacrifice child)

I use the top command to monitor the memory usage and it climbs up over time (as in more executions of mergeExposures(...)) and dips down after the execution but has an general trend upwards and then I get killed when top shows ~85% memory usage.

```
int HDRMaker::mergeExposuresInThread(std::vector<std::string> files)
{

    const int maxThreads = 4;
    int threadsActive = 0;

    if (hdrThreads.size() != maxThreads)
    {
        hdrThreads.resize(files.size());

    }
    // Init status
    hdrThreadsStatus.resize(files.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < hdrThreadsStatus.size(); i++)
    {
        hdrThreadsStatus[i] = 0;
    }

    if (resultImgs.size() != 24)
    {
        resultImgs.resize(24);
    }

    printf("mergeExposuresInThread - start\n");

    int nextImg = 0;

    bool shallWeRun = true;
    while(shallWeRun)
    {

        if (threadsActive <= maxThreads)
        {

            const int pos = nextImg;
            const std::string fname = std::string(files[pos]);
            nextImg++;
            threadsActive++;
            hdrThreadsStatus[pos] = 1;

            hdrThreads[pos]=(new std::thread([this, pos, fname] {
                printf("%d %d %s\n", __LINE__, pos, fname.c_str());
                Mat fusionResult;
                std::string hdrBase = std::string(fname);
                ReplaceStringInPlace(hdrBase, "color", "color_exp");
                printf("mergeExp:%s\n", hdrBase.c_str());
                ReplaceStringInPlace(hdrBase, ".png", "_");

                std::vector<cv::Mat> fusionFrames;
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    std::string expName = std::string(hdrBase + std::to_string(i) + ".png");
                    // printf("%s\n", expName.c_str());
                    cv::Mat exp = imread(hdrBase + std::to_string(i) + ".png");
                    fusionFrames.push_back(exp);
                    exp.release();
                }

                Ptr<MergeMertens> mergeMertens = createMergeMertens();
                mergeMertens->process(fusionFrames, fusionResult);
                cv::Mat rgbResult;
                fusionResult = fusionResult*255;
                fusionResult.convertTo(rgbResult, CV_8UC3);

                accessVectorMutex.lock();
                resultImgs[pos] = rgbResult;
                accessVectorMutex.unlock();




                imwrite(fname, rgbResult); //debug

                printf("Collage ProcessHDRandSaveFile %s end\n", hdrBase.c_str());

                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    fusionFrames[i].release();
                }


                fusionResult.release();
                rgbResult.release();
                mergeMertens.release();

            }));
        }


        if (threadsActive >= maxThreads)
        {
            for (int t = 0; t < hdrThreads.size(); t++)
            {
                accessVectorStatus.lock();
                if (hdrThreadsStatus[t] == 1)
                {
                    accessVectorStatus.unlock();
                    if (hdrThreads[t]->joinable())
                    {
                        hdrThreads[t]->join();
                        delete hdrThreads[t];       
                        hdrThreads[t]=nullptr;
                        accessVectorStatus.lock();
                        hdrThreadsStatus[t] = 2;
                        threadsActive--;
                        accessVectorStatus.unlock();
                        printf("Thread:%d killed\n", t);
                        // break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    accessVectorStatus.unlock();
                }
            }
        }


        bool foundFalse = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < hdrThreadsStatus.size(); i++)
        {
            if (hdrThreadsStatus[i] != 2)
            {
                foundFalse = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (foundFalse)
        {
            shallWeRun = true;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("All thread done exit\n");
            shallWeRun = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int t = 0; t < hdrThreads.size(); t++)
    {
        accessVectorStatus.lock();
        if (hdrThreadsStatus[t] == 1)
        {
            accessVectorStatus.unlock();
            if (hdrThreads[t]->joinable())
            {
                hdrThreads[t]->join();
                delete hdrThreads[t];       
                hdrThreads[t]=nullptr;
                accessVectorStatus.lock();
                hdrThreadsStatus[t] = 2;
                threadsActive--;
                accessVectorStatus.unlock();
                printf("Thread:%d killed\n", t);
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            accessVectorStatus.unlock();
        }
    }


    printf("mergeExposuresInThread - end\n");
    return 1;

}

void ReplaceStringInPlace(std::string& subject, const std::string& search,
                          const std::string& replace)
{
    size_t pos = 0;
    while ((pos = subject.find(search, pos)) != std::string::npos) {
         subject.replace(pos, search.length(), replace);
         pos += replace.length();
    }
}
```

Header

```
int mergeExposuresInThread(std::vector<std::string> files);
std::mutex accessVectorMutex;
std::mutex accessVectorStatus;
std::vector<std::thread*> hdrThreads;
std::vector<int> hdrThreadsStatus;
std::vector<cv::Mat> resultImgs;
```

Calling code

```
mergeExposuresInThread(filesAsStrings); // A list of 24 files
// Do other things (this does not leak without mergeExposuresInThread(...)
for (int i = 0; i < resultImgs.size(); i++)
{
    resultImgs[i].release();
}
```

Comment: Memory going up and up does not mean that you are leaking memory. Freed memory is returned to your program, not to the operating system. If you want to set an upper limit on the ammount of memory your program uses you are going to have to write your own heap allocator.

Comment: @john how come then that I get killed by the OS after some time (Ubuntu 16.04) ?

Comment: I would edit your question to state that. It still doesn't prove that you are leaking memory, it could simply be that your code requires more memory that the OS is prepared to give you.

Comment: Or that you are fragmenting the heap. So the memory is available but not in big enough chunks